# Is it possible to make a call to an Azure API Rest url without a subscription key?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I just want to be able to do a rest call using Azure Web Api Management without needing to pass the subscription-key in the url. Is that possible?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the operation you want invoked?

Comment: I want https://xxxx.azure-api.net/api/returnallstores?subscription-key=<Your subscription key> to be changed to https://xxxx.azure-api.net/api/returnallstores

Comment: Do you mean passing the subscription key in header rather than in URL?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am having an old app calling a service somewhere else than Azure. I have the new app using Azure. I want to have all the service calls go trough azure but i don't want / cannot modify the old app so that it appends the query string.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is having your old service call something first, and have that process forward the calls to Azure and append the subscription key.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing.  I thought in Policies you might be able to use the various set-header, set-query policies, but they are evaluated too late in the process.  Have you found any answer to this @alinulms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure API management allows for anonymous subscriptions.

Create a Product without requiring a subscription (Product -> Settings -> Require Subscription)
Add your API to this product.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-add-products/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

API Management Portal -> Product -> click a product -> Settings -> Require Subscription

However, the subscription key provides identification to the Azure API portal.  Without it, you lose analytics, security, throttling...basically every reason why you would want to want to use API Management in the first place.

Unless you have a reason to uncheck this and still use API management (which you might have), I would recommend letting the user just hit the API directly if you don't want subscription keys.  I only would uncheck this checkbox if I had a special product line for demonstration purposes.